# Where can I find Cognos 10 API?

Tags: api, cognos

I am trying to migrate some code from Cognos 8 to Cognos 10 and am trying to find the developer guide for the Cognos 10 API but can't find it anywhere, I can only find the documentation for Cognos 8. Does any one know where I can find this?

Answer (score 4):

The Cognos 10 SDK is restricted to licensed customers.  Here is a link discussing it:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14587252

I do not see any available public developer's guide.

Answer (score 2):

[Cognos 10 Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247912.pdf) see if it helps. API is restricted to registered users.